# Keras.NET Freezing Application

Tags: .net, keras, scisharp

I am in the process of constructing an application using Keras.NET. Upon executing the `Predict` function within the trained model, it behaves as anticipated during the initial run, successfully generating image predictions. However, when I invoke it for the second time or subsequent times, it becomes unresponsive within the `Predict` method (freezing), failing to complete the operation.

I endeavored to encapsulate the code within a task; nevertheless, the issue persisted unabated.

Comment: I was able to find a solution for this problem. If you're having a similar issue, here's the link to the closed issue, with a comment of how to solve it: [link](https://github.com/SciSharp/Keras.NET/issues/252)